How to create unit test in Jest with a Vue custom directive?
I have a custom vue directive that is to be applied on a custom component. I am trying to write some unit tests for it with Jest but I'm having a hard time attaching the directive to the custom component in the unit test.
My unit test contains below:
wrapper = mount(RcInput, {
    global: {
        directives: {
            "rc-descriptor":RcDescriptor,
        },
    }
});

const input = wrapper.find('input');

My custom component contains:
div v-else-if="type === 'text' || type === 'password'"
        :class="['rcwc-input', `rcwc-${type}-input`]"
        v-rc-descriptor="{serviceUri: serviceUriForUnitTestOnly}" ######## Keep note of this line
    >
        <input
            :type="type"
            :value="modelValue || ''"
            :disabled="disabled"
            :required="required"
            :class="{ 'rcwc-error-input': error }"
            @input="onInput"
            @keydown="onKeydown"
            v-bind="$attrs"
        >
    </div>
    <div v-else />

For some reason I must also add the line:
v-rc-descriptor="{serviceUri: serviceUriForUnitTestOnly}" in the custom component in order for the unit test to even register the custom directive. I've read the documentation: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-directives and I'm pretty sure I'm following the docs but I can't seem to see why the component won't event register the custom directive unless I specify that particular line.
What am I doing wrong?
As a follow up, suppose all I need is:
global: {
        directives: {
            "rc-descriptor":RcDescriptor,
        },
    }

How do I add the custom directive's mock bindings?

It is a component and not directive test, correct? v-rc-descriptor="{serviceUri: serviceUriForUnitTestOnly}" in the custom component in order for the unit test to even register the custom directive - can you clarify what does this mean and why exactly is this a problem? What happens when you don't specify serviceUriForUnitTestOnly?

Essentially if I don't include v-rc-descriptor in my component than the unit test is not going to realise the custom directive is applied to the component. I think this is a problem because from the documentation, it does not indicate the need to for this additional step. From the documentation, adding the directive inside global should suffice for a unit test. Or perhaps I'm wrong and that's just how it's supposed to be done? It just seems a little weird that I have to add additional code in my component to have the unit test pass.

serviceUriForUnitTestOnly is the binding from the directive, if it's missing than it's just null and everything inside the directive using the binding will end up being undefined

global.directives is the substitute for app.directive("rc-descriptor", RcDescriptor). You register it to be available within a test, but if you don't use it, it remains unused. Sorry, it's still unclear if it's directive or component test. Currently it looks like you try to test both, which isn't a unit test. In case it's a component test, provide it with a mocked "rc-descriptor. If it's a directive, wrap it with dummy component that fulfills your expectations
